# Why is the wrong action processing my .ajax request. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery

This is an issue I have been working around for some time now thinking I would eventually stumble on an explaination. I have not and it's now becoming a little more problematic for me.

I used rails-generate-scaffold to create a simple (users and posts) application. This was done after installing jquery and jquery-ui. I added actions "login" and "auth" to the users controller. Login.html.erb contains some javascript that sends .ajax request to the users#auth action passing the login information (email and password) as parameters.

The the template auth.js.erb exists. The "auth" action responds to format.js. The request looks normal, but rails processes the request with the "show" action rather than the "auth" action.

In other words, a request to userscontrollers#auth (via .ajax) is being processed by userscontroller#show (as JS).

The problem goes away if I remove the "resources :users" route that scaffold added (the correct action is then called). But without this route other useful scaffold stuff becomes unuseable (like users#new).

From Gemfile:  gem 'jquery-rails', '>=0.2.6'

Installed jQuery with:  rails generate jquery:install --ui

From ../layouts/application.html.erb

```
<head>
<title>Tab1</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

Here is ./log/development.log to shows the request and the response.

```
Started GET "/users/auth/?email=steve&password=[FILTERED]&_=1326063255777" for 24.11.242.181 at 2012-01-08 17:53:45 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters:   {"email"=>"steve", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "_"=>"1326063255777", "id"=>"auth"}
^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1^[[0m
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with ID=auth):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `show'
```

Suggests that the request --> GET "/users/auth/?email ... is being processed by UsersController#show as JS

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post the relevant lines from your `log/development.log` file so we can see what Rails is choosing to do, and why? It's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like a simple assumption issue - i.e. you're assuming something is happening, but the log will tell you different, and maybe having that part of the log will help us understand why.

Comment: Almost certainly a route conflict; order matters-how'd you add the route?

Comment: Wow, order matters alot. The resource route entries seem to compile routes for all the different verbs, if they come last in routes.rb, they appear use the route information that preseeds them in their compilation. Rake-routes returns several more routes if I put the resource entries last. Thing are working now. Thank You.